# Cannot convert from string to int a column in my data

Tags: python

I have a table with id and prod ids like :

```
       _id          _push_product_id_
0   4   43704
1   7   6361 | 6361 | 6361 | 6361
2   9   30252 | 30252 | 8467 | 38988
3   11  18987 | 17706 | 19543 | 33037
4   12  20144 | 7120
```

I want it to be like :

```
     _id  product_id   count
 0    4      43704       1
 1    7      6361        4
```

I have tried doing this :

```
data = pd.melt(transactions.set_index('_id')['_push_product_id_'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
             id_vars=['_id'],
             value_name='_push_product_id_') \
    .dropna().drop(['variable'], axis=1) \
    .groupby(['_id', '_push_product_id_']) \
    .agg({'_push_product_id_': 'count'}) \
    .rename(columns={'_push_product_id_': 'purchase_count'}) \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename(columns={'_push_product_id_': 'productId'})
data['productId'] = data['productId'].astype(int)
```

and this gives an error as :
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 6361 | 6361 | 6361 | 6361'

```
data = pd.melt(transactions.set_index('_id')['_push_product_id_'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
             id_vars=['_id'],
             value_name='_push_product_id_') \
    .dropna().drop(['variable'], axis=1) \
    .groupby(['_id', '_push_product_id_']) \
    .agg({'_push_product_id_': 'count'}) \
    .rename(columns={'_push_product_id_': 'purchase_count'}) \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename(columns={'_push_product_id_': 'productId'})
data['productId'] = data['productId'].astype(int)
```

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 6361 | 6361 | 6361 | 6361' is the error msg

Comment: You need to convert each element to an int individually, perhaps with join and split? What would be the output of `int(' | ')`?

Comment: same invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' | '

Comment: can you refine the code so that i can get desired table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_push_product_id_` column is a `str` value, but you need it to be a list of `int` in order for `apply(pd.Series)` to work.

We can do this is using `apply()` on that column, with a suitable function to split the values on `'|'`, and convert each element of the result to an int:

```
def split_ints(s):
    return [int(i) for i in s.split(' | ')]

# testing:
print(split_ints('18987 | 17706 | 19543 | 33037'))

# [18987, 17706, 19543, 33037]
```

Then you can use this to transform a column in your dataframe:

```
transactions['_push_product_id_'] = transactions['_push_product_id_'].apply(split_ints)
```

Now your code produces something closer to the desired result:

```
   _id  productId  purchase_count
0   11      17706               1
1   11      18987               1
2   11      19543               1
3   11      33037               1
4   12       7120               1
5   12      20144               1
6    4      43704               1
7    7       6361               4
8    9       8467               1
9    9      30252               2
10   9      38988               1
```